# What are the Moral Implications of starting a futuristic weapon manufacturing company?

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, sharia

As-salamu alaykum, respected scholars,

I have recently found myself fascinated by futuristic weapons and technologies depicted in science-fiction movies. This fascination has led me to dream of establishing a futuristic weapons manufacturing company, creating fingerprint-enabled weapons and even Iron-Man-like suits. My question is whether it would be considered halal (permissible) for me to pursue such a venture?

Additionally, I plan to set up this company in the United States, which is a non-Muslim country. If my company manufactures and supplies guns to the US army and its citizens, would this activity still be permissible according to Islamic principles?

I am seeking guidance on the religious implications of this endeavor and how to navigate the ethical considerations of being involved in the weapons industry. Thank you for your time and valuable insights.

Jazakum Allahu khairan.

Comment: Thank you for taking the effort to think and research about this before starting, instead of jumping straight into it!

Answer (score 1):

In general: Manufacturing weapons is permissible, rather it is encouraged, when the intention is correct. Because it is a means of aiding in Jihad, and comes under the meaning of the verse and hadith:

> وأعدوا لهم ما استطعتم من قوة ومن رباط الخيل ترهبون به عدو الله وعدوكم وآخرين من دونهم لا تعلمونهم الله يعلمهم
>
> And prepare against them whatever you are able of power and of steeds of war by which you may terrify the enemy of Allah and your enemy and others besides them whom you do not know [but] whom Allah knows.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 8:60](https://quran.com/8/60?translations=20)</sup>

> ‏ إن الله ليدخل بالسهم الواحد الثلاثة الجنة صانعه يحتسب في صنعته الخير والرامي به والممد به
>
> Allah will admit three people to Paradise by virtue of one arrow: The one who makes it, seeking reward by making it well; the one who shoots it; and the one who hands it to him.
>
> <sup>— [Ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:2811)</sup>

---

Selling weapons to Harbi non-muslims is haram. Because it strengthens the non-muslims against the muslims, the complete opposite of what Islam prescribes: i.e. achievement of superiority of Islam. Also because they will use the weapons against Muslims. Aiding or enabling the defeat or killing of Muslims is haram. There is Ijma' on this:

> وأما بيع السلاح لأهل الحرب، فحرام بالإجماع
>
> With regard to selling weapons to the Ahl al-Harb, it is haram by consensus.
>
> <sup>— [al-Majmoo‘](https://shamela.ws/book/2186/4819)</sup>